# init from Storyboard "This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder" Swift

Tags: swift

I want to inject a QuizMangerClass from the storyboard.

However I get the error "This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder" .

```
private var quizManagerClass: QuizManagerProtocol

init(quizManager: QuizManagerProtocol) {
    self.quizManagerClass = quizManager
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder, quizManager: QuizManagerProtocol){
    self.quizManagerClass = quizManager
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

// called from SB
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(coder: aDecoder, quizManager: QuizManagerMultiton.createQuizManager())
}
```

Other questions on SO refer to outlets on the storyboard, cells and other trivia that does not apply to this problem at all.

I want to be able to initialise QuizManager so it can be injected during testing, and keep coming up with the same error.

What is the solution?

My current code is here: https://github.com/stevencurtis/quizissue

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by reducing the two inits with

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  self.quizManagerClass = QuizManagerMultiton.createQuizManager()

  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Also, I think your code doesn't run because the QuizManager needs to be instantiatable from an NSCoder.

> "This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder"

Edit: Typos